# Eclipse-Changing startup activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I have two activities in eclipse (Android SDK), named Mainactivity and S2. By default, Mainactivity is the one which executes, but i want to run the activity S2 first and the Mainactivity next. How to do it? I'm an amateur android developer with basic knowledge in java.! So please help me doing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your AndroidManifest file:
In the android name inside the activity, give the package name with the activity name "S2"
 android:name="com.example.S2"

You can see the package name inside the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.S2"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```